# 1 px space top of div, why?

Tags: html, css

Before I move forward with this current nav bar I need to find a solution to remove the 1 px space above the nested div.

Any thoughts? BTW the space is not there when I view locally, the space only shows when viewing via server online.

Thanks in advance :)

BTW there is a closing first div in the html but for some reason it is not showing here.

Link: http://www.ravepreservationproject.com/test/index.htm

CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
}
body a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

#header-wrap {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
background-color: #ff9a2c;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#nav a {padding:11px 10px 12px 10px; font:300 18px 'roboto', sans-serif; float:left;}
#nav a:link { color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff9a2c; }
#nav a:visited { color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff9a2c; }
#nav a:hover { color:#ffffff; background-color:#fff; }
#nav a:active { color:#ffffff   ; background-color:#ff9a2c; }

#nav #purple:hover {background-color:#91008b;}
#nav #blue:hover {background-color:#0200ac;}
#nav #green:hover {background-color:#05bd08;}
#nav #yellow:hover {background-color:#f6fc00;}
#nav #red:hover {background-color:#f91d05;}

#nav img {margin:auto; vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; border:0;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header-wrap">
<div id="header" class="clear">
    <nav id="nav">
        <a id="purple" class="nav_hide" href="#">Home</a>
        <a id="blue" class="nav_hide" href="#">About</a>
        <a id="green" class="nav_hide" href="#">Curate</a>
        <a id="red" class="nav_hide" href="#">Updates</a>
        <a id="purple" class="nav_hide" href="#">Donors</a>
        <a id="blue" class="nav_hide" href="#">Donate</a>
        <a id="green" class="nav_hide" href="#">History</a>
        <a id="red" class="nav_hide" href="#">Gallery</a>

        <a id="red" style="float:right; padding:9px 10px 14px 10px;" href="#"><img src="../../../../wt-pinit.png" height="17" width="14"></a>
        <a id="green" style="float:right; padding:9px 10px 14px 10px;" href="#"><img src="../../../../wt-facebook.png" height="17" width="8"></a>  
        <a id="blue" style="float:right; padding:9px 10px 14px 10px;" href="#"><img src="../../../../wt-twitter-comment.png" height="17" width="26"></a>
        <a id="purple" style="float:right; padding:9px 10px 14px 10px;" href="#"><img src="../../../../wt-twitter-follow.png" height="17" width="26"></a>           
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to set `body * {margin:0;padding:0}` or use a *reset.css*

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your problem? It looks fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Use a proper reset CSS (Eric Meyer's one, e.g.). Also note your HTML is not valid (not unique IDs).

Comment: I tried all suggestions but still have the issue. Looks like issue is only on Chrome on my laptop. IE, FF, looks ok and Chrome on my desktop looks good. Weird! 

Here is a screenshot

http://www.ravepreservationproject.com/test/derp.png

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this type of problem... always use one code i.e `* {margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}`
This code you have to use in .css file, top of the .css file. Means, In my onion always start writing .css file with this code it will never create a problem in your layout...
thank u...

Comment: I tried all suggestions but still have the issue. Looks like issue is only on Chrome on my laptop. IE, FF, looks ok and Chrome on my desktop looks good. Weird! 

Here is a screenshot

http://www.ravepreservationproject.com/test/derp.png